# Dynamically create List C#

Tags: c#, list, dynamic

**In a nutshell:**

I have a list with items named Categories. For each of those items in the list Categories I have a xml file:

```
   System.IO.File.Create(Categories[listPicker.SelectedIndex] + ".xml");
```

The created item is serialized into a xml file with the name of the selected index.

**The problem:**

The problem is that for each item in categories an xml file needs to be deserialized to a list, because each object of categories must be another list because it also contains items.

But there does not exist a list for deserialization of the xml file:

Deserialization:

```
Serialize.Deserialize(Variable list name , Categories[1]+".xml");
```

So how do i dynamically create lists or can you provide a better solution to this problem?

Comment: So you want to have Lists available in your application, populated by data held in an XML file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if each list has a different name, the structure of the content is the same. Text/Description and Value.

I would create a class for the Item. Something like

```
public class ComboItem{
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

Then I would create another class for the List of ComboItem that each XML File would have

```
public class ComboItemList
{
    public ComboItemList()
    {
        ComboItems = new List<ComboItem>();
    }

    [XmlArray("ComboItems"), XmlArrayItem("ComboItem")]
    public List<ComboItem> ComboItems { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Serialize/Deserialize Helper. Something like

```
    #region static T DeserializeObject( string xml, Encoding encoding )

    /// <summary>
    ///   Deserialize an Xml String to an [object]
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Object Type to Deserialize</typeparam>
    /// <param name="xml">Xml String to Deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">System.Text.Encoding Type</param>
    /// <returns>Default if Exception, Deserialize object if successful</returns>
    /// <example>
    ///   // UTF-16 Deserialize
    ///   [object] = SerializationHelper<ObjectType>DeserializeObject( xml, Encoding.Unicode )
    /// </example>
    /// <example>
    ///   // UTF-8 Deserialize
    ///   [object] = SerializationHelper<ObjectType>DeserializeObject( xml, Encoding.UTF8 )
    /// </example> 
    public static T DeserializeObject(string xml, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml)) { return default(T); }
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(xml)))
            {
                // No settings need modifying here
                XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();

                using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream, xmlReaderSettings))
                {
                    return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserialize an Xml String to an [object] with UTF8 as Encoding
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">Xml String to Deserialize</param>
    /// <returns>Default if Exception, Deserialize object if successful</returns>
    /// <example>
    ///   [object] = SerializationHelper<ObjectType>DeserializeObject( xml )
    /// </example>
    public static T DeserializeObjectFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("The file {0}, don't exist.", filePath));
        }
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath);

        string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();

        return DeserializeObject(xml, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```

that I would call like this

```
string filePath01 = "PATH TO FILE 01";
List<ComboItem> List01 = SerializationHelper<ComboItem>.DeserializeObjectFromFile(filePath01);

string filePath02 = "PATH TO FILE 02";
List<ComboItem> List02 = SerializationHelper<ComboItem>.DeserializeObjectFromFile(filePath02);
```

List01 and List02 would have the contents of File01 and File02. Repeat for every file you have.

With a better architecture, you could make some properties in base class, that could be singleton, and would only load each file, only once, increasing the performance.

Comment: LEGEND! Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need. This is a very good solution to my problem!